# Converses of Integrability Theorems | Are They True?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I am a first-semester BSc. Engineering student and I have been studying **Riemann Integrability** as part of my coursework. Recently, I came across some theorems in the lecture notes on this topic. While studying, I got confused about these theorems and would appreciate some clarification.

Following are the theorems,

> ***$f: [a, b] → R$ is bounded, and $f$ is integrable on $[c, b]$ for all $c ∈ (a, b)$, then $f$ is integrable on $[a, b]$. An analogous result holds at
> the other endpoint.***
>
> ***Let $f$ be a bounded function on $[a, b]$ that is continuous on every subinterval $[c, b]$ where $c ∈ (a, b)$. Then $f$ is integrable on $[a, b]$.
> An analogous result holds at the other endpoint.***
>
> ***If $f$ is a bounded function on $[a, c]$ and integrable on $[a, b]$ and $[b, c]$, where $a < b < c$, then $f$ is integrable on $[a, c]$.***

However, my confusion lies in the definition of the theorem.

**Can we ascertain whether the converses of these theorems are also true and therefore they're *' if and only if* cases?**

That,

> ***If $f$ is integrable on [a, b] then $f: [a, b] → R$ is bounded, and $f$ is integrable on $[c, b]$ for all $c ∈ (a, b).$***
>
> ***If $f$ is integrable on $[a, b]$ then $f$ is a bounded function on $[a, b]$ that is continuous on every subinterval $[c, b]$ where $c ∈ (a, b).$***
>
> ***If $f$ is integrable on $[a, c]$ then $f$ is a bounded function on $[a, c]$ and integrable on $[a, b]$ and $[b, c]$, where $a < b < c$.***

are true?

(I would appreciate it if you could correct me if the above statements are incorrect **or** partially correct.)

Comment: Integrability does not imply boundedness. It's easy to find counterexamples.

Comment: Which integral are you dealing with? Is it the Riemann integral or the Lebesgue integral?

Comment: First-semester BSc in Engineering implies Riemann integrability

Answer (score 1):

By Lebesgue's theorem, $f$ is integrable $\iff $ set of discontinuities of $f$ has measure zero. From this one can make a conclusion about integrable function being integrable on every subinterval. Boundedness is the very condition needed to define a **proper Riemann** integral on $[a, b]$, so it always follows. For improper integrals this is not true.

As for the second statement, integrability does not imply continuity. This is true by Lebesgue and you can also find a trivial counterexample, such as piecewise constant function.